# Как развернуть QIcon?PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, qpushbutton, rotate, qicon

Допустим у меня есть некая `QPushButton`, на которую я хочу установить повернутое изображение `QIcon` на 90 градусов.

Как мне это сделать? Заранее спасибо!

```
card = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
card.setIcon(QIcon('image.png'))
card.setIconSize(QSize(99, 74))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class RotateMe(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RotateMe, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self._pixmap    = QtGui.QPixmap()
        self._animation = QtCore.QVariantAnimation(
            self,
            startValue=0.0,
            endValue=360.0,
            duration=1000,
            valueChanged=self.on_valueChanged
        )

    def set_pixmap(self, pixmap):
        self._pixmap = pixmap
        self.setPixmap(self._pixmap)

    def start_animation(self):
        if self._animation.state() != QtCore.QAbstractAnimation.Running:
            self._animation.start()

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(QtCore.QVariant)
    def on_valueChanged(self, value):
        t = QtGui.QTransform()
        t.rotate(value)
        self.setPixmap(self._pixmap.transformed(t))


class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        label    = RotateMe(alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        img_path = os.path.join('D:/_Qt/img','next.svg')
        label.set_pixmap(QtGui.QPixmap(img_path))
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Bращать')
        button.clicked.connect(label.start_animation)
        button.clicked.connect(self.onRotate)               # <---

        self.angle = 0                                      # <---
        self.image_fname = ('Shape_1.png')                  # <---
        self.card = QtWidgets.QPushButton()                 # <---
        self.card.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(self.image_fname))    # <---
        self.card.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(99, 74))         # <---

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.addWidget(label)
        lay.addWidget(self.card)
        lay.addWidget(button)

    def onRotate(self):                                     # <---
        self.angle += 90
        t = QtGui.QTransform().rotate(self.angle)
        pix = QtGui.QPixmap(self.image_fname).transformed(t)
        image_rotated = '%s_rotated.png' % (os.path.splitext(self.image_fname)[0])
        pix.save(image_rotated)
        self.card.setIcon(QtGui.QIcon(image_rotated))       


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Widget()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]